# Vue.js progress bar

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm using `vue.js 2.0` I've got this method:

```
calculatePercentage(option) {
    let totalVotes = 0;

    this.poll.options.forEach((option) => {
        totalVotes+= option.votes.length;
    });

    return option.votes.length / totalVotes * 100;
}
```

This is my bootstrap progress bar:

```
<div class="span6">
    <div v-for="option in poll.options">
        <strong>{{ option.name }}</strong><span class="pull-right">{{ calculatePercentage(option) }}%</span>
        <div class="progress progress-danger active" aria-valuenow="12">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 15%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the `calculatePercentage(option);` is working properly. But how do I bind this to the style (`style="width: 15%;"`) ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can bind inline style to vue data as explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1). All you need to do is return values from `calculatePercentage`  and use it in style like following:

```
<div class="span6">
    <div v-for="option in poll.options">
        <strong>{{ option.name }}</strong><span class="pull-right">{{ calculatePercentage(option) }}%</span>
        <div class="progress progress-danger active" aria-valuenow="12">
            <div class="bar" v-bind:style="{width: calculatePercentage(option) + '%'}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```